# [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}" is not updating the model value for the second time if any model change happened

Tags: angular

[ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}" is not working as expected after updating the version to angular 16.

first time on blur textbox, model value is assigned and for the second time any change in the textbox, value remains unchanged not updating the latest one, displaying previous value only.

Note: before updating to angular 16, earlier version is angular 13, it works fine in version 13

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}"
(change)="isRequiredValiation('lastName')" />